# How to load binary content to clipboard without anything removed or manipulated? (Autohotkey)

Tags: windows, autohotkey, clipboard, onenote

I have binary content stored in a file (containing previous clipboard content) is being modified (without purpose or adding code for this) every time I try to load it to clipboard.

The binary content represents organised paragraphs on OneNote copied to clipboard. In order to be able to use later, I saved the clipboard binary contents to test.clip file using:

```
FileAppend, %ClipboardAll%, C:\My\Path\test.clip
```

Then when I try to retrieve the binary file test.clip contents to clipboard using:

```
FileRead, Clipboard, *c C:\My\Path\test.clip
```

And paste to OneNote, I get incomplete paragraphs from the ones that was copied before and saved to the binary file.

I tried to check the difference between the old binary file `test.clip` and the clipboard content after loading this file. I saved the new clipboard content to test2.clip after retrieving test.clip to check if there's something manipulated or not using:

```
FileRead, Clipboard, *c C:\My\Path\test.clip
FileAppend, %ClipboardAll%, C:\My\Path\test2.clip
```

I compared the two files [test.clip](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/omarabdelsalam/f26b77174e5b9fa18ba58052bb5137e5/raw/8e32e6578a2abe779997414192feb8e82707c7a6/test.clip) and [test2.clip](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/omarabdelsalam/f26b77174e5b9fa18ba58052bb5137e5/raw/a29eca48f2a5e3b807037a9c4c975ca9461dc89e/test2.clip) (Which are expected to be the same). I found that there's a block of binary code (at the end of the file) was removed after each load for test.clip to clipboard (The removed block is marked red in the below image):
[image]

**How could I fix** this to load the binary clipboard content stored in test.clip without getting anything removed or manipulated from the actual file content?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `%ClipboardAll%` here. Just use `%clipboard%`.

"*Clipboard is a built-in variable that reflects the current contents of the Windows clipboard if those contents can be expressed as text.* 
**By contrast**, **ClipboardAll** **contains everything on the clipboard, such as pictures and formatting**." 

- https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm

Quoting from the docs again, I think i see your problem: "**If ClipboardAll cannot retrieve one or more of the data objects** *(formats) on the clipboard*, **they will be omitted** *but all the remaining objects will be stored.*"

As an example:

```
F4::
FileAppend, %Clipboard%, clipboardcontents.clip
FileRead, Clipboard, clipboardcontents.clip
```